# I need help setting up an integral to calculate part of a cylinder below a sphere and above a plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let B be the part of solid cylinder {(x, y, z) : $x^2 + y^2 ≤ 1$} that is:

• below the hemisphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4, z ≥ 0$;

• above the plane x + z = −2.

Compute the volume of B

I really need help setting up a **double** integral for this problem. I have only learnt Fubini's theorem, setting up integrals over general and rectangle regions, and changing variables to polar with the use of the Jacobian.

This is one of the practice problems assigned to practice for my test in 2 days. All I know is that I have to set this up as a **double** integral in terms of x and y then I will have to change it into polar coordinates. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer a triple integral?

Comment: No because we haven't gotten that far in the course. Sorry

Comment: @Maam what would the triple integral look like just out of curiosity.

Comment: What disturbs me, is the plane: if $z\geq 0,$ then $-x-2\geq 0,$ which gives only $x=-2$ due to the sphere. Isn't there a typo?

Comment: @Maam no there isn't a typo I asked my professor

Comment: From $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ one gets $-1\leq x \leq 1.$ From $x+z+2=0$ and $z \geq 0$ follows $x \leq -2.$ It is incompatible or, if you wish, $B=\emptyset$ and the volume is $0.$

Comment: Isn't it above that whole plane so x should be greater than 2 right?

Comment: One of the conditions $z \geq 0$ or $x+z \geq -2$ (I write this inequality since we are above the plane) is needless.

Comment: So it's just area of the cylinder below the sphere. What would that integral look like? I don't know how to setup the integral

Comment: So the integral in my opinion is $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{4-r^2} rdrd \theta$

Comment: Right. Do you understand why?

Comment: Actually no. This is just intuition I'm surprised I'm correct. Can you explain me please